# Programatically creating a triangle grid from centerpoint on graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, kineticjs, graph-theory

Im going to try to explain this as best as I can.

I have a centerpoint defined on a canvas element where I am using Kinetic JS to draw triangles.

What I want to do, is create an array of coordinates based on the center point of the excircle radius of a triangle (Kinetic draws regular polygons by using the excircle radius) to see how many of the triangle center points will fit on the canvas in a grid structure. Think this but bigger:

[image]

Now Ive already done this with squares because they fall in the same interval from the centerpoint on both the X axis and the Y axis. However with triangles this ends up being different due to where the radius center point of the excircle on a triangle is. Here is a semi clear picture illustrating the interval difference:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/x894tlF.png]

Now these coordinates HAVE to be pushed into an array in a very specific way, or else the way I have planned for them to interact will not work correctly.

Ultimately I want to find the bottom most triangle coordinate possible. Find out if that triangle is flipped at 180 degrees or 0 degrees respectively while making sure the centerpoint of the entire canvas is touching the vertex of a triangle.

Sounds complicated? It is. Ive been trying several different methods and racking my brain for two weeks now, and I cant figure out an algorithm that will allow me to do this from any canvas size possible.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you need.  Do you just need to draw a grid of triangles (as in your darker image)?  If so you can draw a series of hexagons with each hexagon vertex connected to its centerpoint.  You can translate your group of hexagons so that a hexagon centerpoint is over the canvas centerpoint.

Comment: @markE Its more that I need to find the most left most/ bottom most triangle's x,y coordinate and it's orientation (180 degrees or 0 degrees). Once I have that one triangle, I can populate the rest of grid. And I need to find this one x,y coordinate where the center triangles are always in the same orientation and where the canvas size is variable.

Comment: Does the circle center exactly fall at an intersection?

Comment: @Tarik Not necessarily. The excircle radius of the triangle makes the centerpoint of that triangle scatter at a certain interval because of the orientation of the triangle on the grid with relation to it's neighbor. To better illustrate Im trying to find the most bottom left triangle on a plane with respect to the centerpoint. The orientation and position of this triangle must be in such a way that the triangles around the center point of the plane form a hexagon with the center point of the hexagon being the center point of the plane. The plane size is variable.

Comment: @JSArrakis You might want to post this in the math stack exchange. I believe they would respond more quickly and with much mathematical rigor.